# How to handle relative time calculation if Client Browser is set 10 mins ahead?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I have a problem with Relative time. Currently, we send the server Unix time to the client and we take Client-time and Server-time diff to show the relative time. In our case, the Client has set his time 10 mins ahead. In this case, our relative time shows "10 mins ago" for "now" (instant notifications). Has anyone had this problem? Please suggest me a solution to handle this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So you send down current server time and adjust the user's clock time based on that time.... So you are doing an offset in your caculations.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far